# What does 2084 mean when permissions needed for app to overlay other apps

Tags: android, kotlin, permissions

I am checking some GitHub repositories and there is this line of code

```
    private val CODE_DRAW_OVER_OTHER_APP_PERMISSION = 2084
```

Does anyone know what it means? I am trying to google it but i cannot find something relevant.

I changed it to `200` instead of `2084` and it was still working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of the `CODE_DRAW_OVER_OTHER_APP_PERMISSION` constant is an arbitrary number selected by the developer who wrote the code. Despite the similarly sounding name of the constant, it's not a system permission, so not a part of the Android SDK, therefore searching official docs will help you very little.

It is simply a code value the developer chose to uniquely identify certain functionality, permissions, etc. Check the original sources to see how this constant is used so you will get the picture. That said, the value itself is likely insignificant, and changing it to `200` should make no difference as changing to anything else (as long as the new value doesn't cause any conflicts, such as overlapping with something else, which seems quite improbable to me anyway).

So to answer "why 2084?", I'd say "because 200" (or "because 2137" etc)

Comment: If the number is actually *20**48*** then it might have been chosen as a bit flag, intended to be combined with other flags in a bit field, so it might not be a completely random choice in that sense